# How to iterate through JSON objects (results of twitter api search) in Python and save to a CSV file?

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.7

AIM: need to find out how to parse data from api search below into a CSV file. The search returns results in the following format:

```
[(u'Bertille Maciag', 10), (u'Peter Prior', 5), (u'Chris OverPar Duguid', 4), (u
'Selby Dhliwayo', 4), (u'FakeBitch!', 4), (u'Django Unchianed UK', 4), (u'Padrai
g Lynch ', 4), (u'Jessica Gunn', 4), (u'harvey.', 4), (u'Wowphotography', 3)]
```

I'm a newbie to python and any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import twitter, json, operator
#Construct Twitter API object
searchApi = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
#Get trends
query = "#snow"
tweeters = dict()

for i in range(1,16):
    response = searchApi.search(q=query, rpp=100, page=i)
    tweets = response['results']
    for item in tweets:
        tweet = json.loads(json.dumps(item))
        user = tweet['from_user_name']
        #print user
        if user in tweeters:
            # print "list already contains", user
            tweeters[user] += 1
        else:
           tweeters[user] = 1

sorted_tweeters = sorted(tweeters.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),     reverse=True)  

print len(tweeters)
print tweeters

print sorted_tweeters[0:10]
print 'Done!'
```

Comment: Why do you dump and load the item object instead of just loading?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have all the hard bits working, and are just missing the 'save to csv' part.

```
import collections
import twitter, json, operator
#Construct Twitter API object
searchApi = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
#Get trends
query = "#snow"
tweeters = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for i in range(1,16):
    response = searchApi.search(q=query, rpp=100, page=i)
    tweets = response['results']
    for item in tweets:
        user = item['from_user_name']
        #print user
        tweeters[user] += 1

sorted_tweeters = sorted(tweeters.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)  

str_fmt = u'%s\u200E, %d \n'
with open('test_so.csv','w') as f_out:
    for twiters in sorted_tweeters:
        f_out.write((str_fmt % twiters).encode('utf8'))
```

You need the 'u' on the format string and `encode` because you have non-ascii charachters in the user names.  `u'\200E` is the ltr marker so that the csv file will look right with rtl language user names.

I also cleaned up the iteration code a bit, by using a `defaultdict` you don't need check if a key exists, if it does not exist, the generator function is called and it's value is returned (in this case 0).

`item` is already a `dict`, there is no need to convert it to a json string and then back to a `dict`

Comment: Hi tcaswell,thanks for your fast reply.placed the code between tweeters = sorted(tweeters.iteriitems().....and...print len(tweeters). Received the following error message C:\Users\lenovo>python C:\Users\lenovo\workspace\test3\ass3_working.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
from .api import Twitter, TwitterError, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterResponse
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twitter-1.9.0-py2.7.egg\twitter\api.py", l
ine 20, in <module>
  import json
File "C:\Users\lenovo\workspace\test3\json.py", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONEncoder'

Comment: @masterkilla Fixed a typo `tweeters` -> `sorted_tweeters`  I really have no idea what code you actually ran and can make no sense of the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [python CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module? using your output:

```
import csv, os

x = [(u'Bertille Maciag', 10), (u'Peter Prior', 5), (u'Chris OverPar Duguid', 4), (u'Selby Dhliwayo', 4), (u'FakeBitch!', 4), (u'Django Unchianed UK', 4), (u'Padraig Lynch ', 4), (u'Jessica Gunn', 4), (u'harvey.', 4), (u'Wowphotography', 3)]

f = open("/tmp/yourfile.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for i in x:
    writer.writerow(i)

f.close()
```